# docker custom nginx container failed to start

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to build a nginx image from scratch (instead of using the official nginx image)

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx    
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

COPY ./files/ /var/www/html/

CMD service nginx start
```

And this is my `nginx.conf` file under current directory.

```
server {

    root /var/www/html

    location / {
        index.html
    }

}
```

And my dummy `index.html` file under `./files` folder

```
<p1>hello world</p1>
```

I run this command

```
docker build -t hello-world .
```

And

```
docker run -p 80:80 hello-world
```

But I got error saying

```
 * Starting nginx nginx
   ...fail!
```

What maybe the issue?

Answer (score 16):

#### Don't use "service xyz start"

To run a server inside a container, don't use the `service` command. That is a script which will run the requested server in the background, and then exit. When the script exits, the container will stop (because that script was the primary process).

Instead, directly run the command that the `service` script would have started for you. Unless it exits or crashes, the container should remain running.

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx"]
```

#### nginx.conf is missing the events section

This is required. Something like:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
```

#### The server directive is not a top-level element

You have `server { }` at the top level of the nginx.conf, but it has to be inside a protocol definition such as `http { }` to be valid.

```
http {
    server {
        ...
```

#### nginx directives end with a semicolon

These are missing at the end of the `root` statement and your `index.html` line.

#### Missing the "index" directive

To define the index file, use `index`, not just the filename by itself.

```
index index.html;
```

#### There is no HTML element "p1"

I assume you meant to use `<p>` here.

```html
<p>hello world</p>
```

---

#### Final result

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

COPY ./files/ /var/www/html/

CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx"]
```

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    server {

        root /var/www/html;

        location / {
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
daemon off;
```

Comment: What does this line stand for? ```RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf```
Thanks.

Comment: @LuisMilanese That adds the string `daemon off;` at the end of the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in the resulting image.

Comment: @LuisMilanese I added that to the answer; seems it was missing in the "final result" box.

Answer (score 4):

one can use directly the official image of nginx in docker hub, just start your docker file with this line : `FROM nginx`

here is an example of docker file that you can use :

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY static-html-directory /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

as you see there is no need to use a `CMD` to run your nginx server

Comment: Tried your way (except no special config used), but still can't make nginx start automatically:


Manual nginx start from within a container helps, but can't make it start automatically.
Tried even `CMD /usr/sbin/nginx` to no avail.


Any help appreciated.